# Angular 2 meteor component doesn't recieve data on page reload (if route has a canActivate)

Tags: angular, meteor, angular2-meteor

I'm working on a Meteor app with Angular 2 and I've run into an issue where my components won't recieve data from a subscribed collection when the page is first reloaded, if the route for the page includes a `canActivate` guard (in this case it's a simple is-logged-in condition).

For now I'm going to work around it (by not using guards) but what's the probable cause? I'm quite new to Meteor so any assistance is welcome.

For reference my component is super simple and looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hobbit-list',
  template: template.default,
})
export class HobbitListComponent implements OnInit {
  hobbits : Observable<Hobbit[]>;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.hobbits = Hobbits.find({}).zone();
    MeteorObservable.subscribe('hobbits').subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: i have used canActivate in one of  my angular 2 meteor project. this code is ok. can you show me where you are getting problem ? show your canActivate code. one issue is your unsubscribe is missing